# Find x in degrees: (there souls be 2 answers from 0 degrees to 360 degrees) 5cos(x)=2sec(x)-3

Tags: trigonometry

$2(1/\cos(x))-5\cos(x)-3=0$

$(2/\cos(x))-5\cos(x)-3=0$

$2-5\cos(x)-3=\cos(x)$

$-5\cos(x)-1=\cos(x)$

$-6\cos(x)=1$

$\cos(x)=-1/6$

$x=99.6$
Reference angle$=80.4$

$180+80.4=260.4$

$x=99.6^o$, $260.4^o$

I did this, but when I checked it, it didn't work. Is this correct?

Comment: Algebraic glitch. When you take your initial equation and multiply through by $\cos x$ you should get $5\cos^2 x=2-3\cos x$. Quadratic in $\cos x$.

Comment: From $\frac{2}{\cos x}-5\cos x-3=0$ you got $2-5\cos x-3=\cos x$, which is incorrect. By multiplying both sides by $\cos x$ you get $2-5\cos^2 x-3\cos x=0$ (which is a quadratic in $\cos x$)

Comment: Could someone please tell me why my method is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is wrong because, it seems, you really have not a method!

When you have an equation of the form:
$$
\dfrac{a}{X}+bX+C=0
$$
How can you solve it?

The first step is to have a common denominator:
$$
\dfrac{a+bX^2+cX}{X}=0
$$

Than, if $X\ne 0$ you can multiply both sides by $X$ and you find the equation:
$$
bX^2+cX+a=0
$$

that can be solved for $X$.

In your case $X=\cos x$.

Can you do the work?